# Why does parseInt() return a wrong integer?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to understand why parseInt() returns a wrong result when I parse 1329879643513216515489679841651614 like this:

```
parseInt(1329879643513216515489679841651614);//supposed to return the number yet returns 1
```

and how can I parse that number as a full number please?

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html

Comment: JS can't count that high, so why do you need to?

Comment: There is no point in passing a number to `parseInt`. If you used the string `"1329879643513216515489679841651614"`, you would get `1.3298796435132165e+33`, which makes more sense than `1`.